# Moving Enemys On A Path Problem Pygame - Tower Defense Game

Tags: python, pygame

[image][image]so I am trying to make a tower defense game and I am trying to move my player in a path but I am having a problem with that

so I am trying to make it so each time the player reaches that point
it moves another direction x or y but this is happening [video](https://gyazo.com/9d321120c0c9032277e62a4566bb6211)

I am not sure how to actully make enemys move on a path but this is my first attempt

```
    # move the enemy
    if playerman.x < 380:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
    else:
        playerman.y -= playerman.speed

    if playerman.y  > 116:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed

    else:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed
```

my full code

```
import pygame,random

pygame.init()

# window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,700))


#
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 3
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("weak1.png")
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect,2)
        player_rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
        player_rect.centerx += 3 # 10 is just an example
        player_rect.centery += -10 # 15 is just an example
        window.blit(self.image, player_rect)


# check points for the player to turn
class check():
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

red = (0,255,0)
check1 = check(380,376,50,50,red)
check2 = check(380,116,50,50,red)
check3 = check(628,116,50,50,red)
check4 = check(640,546,50,50,red)



checks = [check1,check2,check3,check4]

# player
white = (255,255,255)
playerman = player(50,376,50,50,white)


# the background for my gameee
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")


# redraw window
def draw():
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    window.blit(bg,(0,0))
    playerman.draw()

    # the check points
    for check in checks:
        check.draw()

# the main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False


    # move the enemy
    if playerman.x < 380:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
    else:
        playerman.y -= playerman.speed

    if playerman.y  > 116:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed

    else:
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed

        
    


    # redraw the window
    draw()


    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented 2 `if`-`else`-statemsts.

> ```py
> if playerman.x < 380:
>    playerman.x += playerman.speed
> else:
>    playerman.y -= playerman.speed
>
> if playerman.y  > 116:
>    playerman.x += playerman.speed
>
> else:
>    playerman.x -= playerman.speed
> ```

Both statements are executed and the player performs 2 movements in every frame.

You have to implement a single `if`-`elif`-statement, where only 1 case is executed in every frame. For instance:

```py
while runninggame:
    # [...]

    if playerman.x < 380:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
    elif playerman.y > 116 and playerman.x < 628:
        playerman.y -= playerman.speed
    elif playerman.x < 628:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
    elif playerman.y < 546:
        playerman.y += playerman.speed
    elif playerman.x < 900:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed

    # [...]
```

Comment: I made a new map and I am having a problem when my enemies are going back down [script](https://pastebin.com/qBK2w0VV) my full code [script(https://pastebin.com/Uy0Q9QZe) not sure why the last two arent working at all*** I have updated the map and the enemies***